# Powershell input piping issue

Tags: powershell, piping

I am not able to run this simple powershell program

```
[int]$st1 = $input[0]
[int]$st2 = $input[1]
[int]$st3 = $input[2]
[int]$pm = $input[3]
[int]$cm = $input[4]

$MedMarks = $st1 + $st2 + $st3 - ($pm + $cm)
Write-Host "Med Marks  $MedMarks"
```

I am trying to run it with input pipeline like this

> 120, 130, 90, 45, 30 | .\sample_program.ps1

I am consistently getting this error

```
Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple" value of type
"System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple" to type "System.Int32".
```

Comment: `$InputArray = @($input); [int]$st1 = $InputArray[0]; ...`

Comment: @PetSerAl ... this is correct, but why in comments ? :) please move it to answer so that i can mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect `$input` like this:

```
PS> function f { $input.GetType().FullName } f
System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple
```

then you can notice, that `$input` is not a collection, but an enumerator for one. So, you do not have random access with indexer for bare `$input`. If you really want to index `$input`, then you need to copy its content into array or some other collection:

```
$InputArray = @( $input )
```

then you can index `$InputArray` as normal:

```
[int]$st1 = $InputArray[0]
[int]$st2 = $InputArray[1]
[int]$st3 = $InputArray[2]
[int]$pm = $InputArray[3]
[int]$cm = $InputArray[4]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't index into `$input` like that.

You can utilize `ForEach-Object`:

```
$st1,$st2,$st3,$pm,$cm = $input |ForEach-Object { $_ -as [int] }
```

or (preferably), use named parameters:

```
param(
    [int]$st1,
    [int]$st2,
    [int]$st3,
    [int]$pm,
    [int]$cm
)

$MedMarks = $st1 + $st2 + $st3 - ($pm + $cm)
Write-Host "Med Marks  $MedMarks"
```

Comment: This one works , but i will go with @PetSalAl 's response , its a bit neat